# Not getting an output in website even after I have passed objects in views.py coming from models.py

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

Not getting an output in website even after I have passed objects in views.py coming from models.py …

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from travello.models import destination

def index(request):

    mumbai = destination()
    mumbai.name = 'Mumbai'

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'mumbai': mumbai})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class destination:
    id: int
    image: str
    name: str
    desc: str
    price: float
```

index.html

`<div class="destination_title"><a href="destinations.html">{{mumbai.name}}</a></div>`

it must have to render the output .. but it cant !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't saved your instance in the **destination** model. try the following:

```
mumbai = destination(name='mumbai')
mumbai.save()
```